# Obter ou retornar uma variável para o angular

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

Tenho um método onde faço uma determinada validação e a depender do cenário, preciso retornar apenas um alerta e continuar com a requisição ou um possível *BadRequest* retornando também uma mensagem.

Pensei em tentar acessar uma variável dentro do meu *if* utilizando o angular. Ou enviar algum retorno para meu *controller* do *angular*.

Preciso obter a variável que está no *if* :

> (if (damMesAnterior != null))

Em caso dela atender essa validação.

```
private async Task VerificarDam(NotaViewModel nota, Prestador prestador)
    {
        var timezone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. South America Standard Time");
        var dataAtual = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, timezone);

        if (dataAtual.Day >= 16)
        {
            var damDoisMesesAnterior = await (DbContext.ValidarPagamentoDAM(nota.Competencia.Value, prestador.Id));

            var damMesAnterior = await (DbContext.VerificarDamCompAnterior(nota.Competencia.Value, prestador.Id));

            if (damMesAnterior != null)
            {
                //Nesse bloco que preciso enviar essa variavel para o front

                var msg = "Mensagem de teste atraso.....";
            }

            if (damDoisMesesAnterior != null)
            {
                if (prestador.DataLiberacao != null)
                {
                    if (prestador.DataLiberacao < dataAtual)
                    {
                        BadRequest(
                            "Existem pendências. Entre em contato com ...");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Controller angular onde obtenho os dados da requisição:

```
    $scope.emitir = function () {
    notaService.emitir($scope.nota).then(function (results) {
        var nota = results.data;

        logService.success('teste mensagem de sucesso.');

        var email = nota.user.email;
        notaService.emitirXML(nota.value2.prestador.value1, nota.value2, nota.value3).then(function (resultsXML) {
            if (email) {
                var url = 'nota.html#/nota/' + nota.prestador.value1 + '/' + nota.value2 + '/' + notaGerada.verificador;
                var baseLen = $location.absUrl().length - $location.url().length;
                url = $location.absUrl().substring(0, baseLen - 1) + url;
                notaService.enviarNota(url, email).then(function (results) {
                    notaService.apagarXML(nota.prestador.value1, nota.value2, nota.value3).then(function (result) {
                    }, function (error)
                        {
                        logService.log(error);
                        console.log(error);
                        });
                },
                    function (error)
                    {
                        logService.log(error);
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            }
        }, function (error) {
            logService.log(error);
        });
        $scope.newNota();
        $scope.initNota();
        $window.open('nota.html#/nota/' + nota.prestador.value1 + '/' + nota.value2 + '/' + nota.value3);


    }, function (error) {
        logService.log(error);
        $scope.nota.valid = true;
    });
};
```

Método é onde faço determinadas validações e retorno para o método publico(que é minha action), que é acessado pelo angular:

```
   public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Emitir(NotaViewModel nota)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        var prestador = await DbContext.GetContribuinteByUserIdAsync(this.User.Identity.GetUserId());

        await VerificarDam(nota, prestador);

        var valueNota = new Nota
        {
            Valor1 = nota.Valor1,
            Valor2 = nota.Valor2,
            Valor3 = nota.Valor3,
            Valor = nota.CofiValorns,
        };
        DbContext.Servicos.Add(valueNota);

        await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        nota = await GetNotaAsync(valueNota);

        return Ok(nota);
    }
```

Comment: Esse método **VerificarDam** é uma `action` do seu `controller`?

Comment: Tem como adicionar esse método publico na pergunta?

Comment: É um método de cadastro básico. Se realmente precisar, posso compartilhar o código.

Comment: é que o retorno para o angular fica nesse método de acesso, posso fazer um exemplo sem vê-lo, mas é melhor vendo

Comment: Vou compartilhar então. Só um segundo.

Comment: no seu `IHttpActionResult` você já retorna um objeto do tipo "nota"(`return Ok(nota);`), se for retornar algo do `VerificarDam` vai mudar esse retorno, é isso que deseja?

Comment: Isso. Mas essa mensagem só preciso emitir de acordo as regras aplicadas nela no método. Pode acontecer a situação em que eu possa também realizar um insert e nele n retornar nenhuma dessas mensagens da validação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode retornar um `json` com as informações que deseja

seu código pode ser assim:

Foi criado uma classe para tratar retorno do método, nela foi adicionado um campo para status e outro para mensagem

o método de verificação retorna um objeto do tipo `retorno` e, por fim, no `controller` é verificado o status e é retornado esse objeto.

no angular você consegue capturar esse retorno e tratar a mensagem

```
public class Retorno
{
     public int StatuCode { get; set; }
     public string MensagemRetorno { get; set; }
}

public async Task<Retorno> VerificarDam(NotaViewModel nota, Prestador prestador)
{
    var timezone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. South America Standard Time");
    var dataAtual = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, timezone);

    if (dataAtual.Day >= 16)
    {
        var damDoisMesesAnterior = await (DbContext.ValidarPagamentoDAM(nota.Competencia.Value, prestador.Id));

        var damMesAnterior = await (DbContext.VerificarDamCompAnterior(nota.Competencia.Value, prestador.Id));

        if (damMesAnterior != null)
        {
            return new Retorno{
                StatuCode = 200,
                MensagemRetorno = "Mensagem de teste atraso....."
            };
        }

        if (damDoisMesesAnterior != null)
        {
            if (prestador.DataLiberacao != null)
            {
                if (prestador.DataLiberacao < dataAtual)
                {
                    return new Retorno{
                        StatuCode = 400,
                        MensagemRetorno = "Existem pendências. Entre em contato com ..."
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return new Retorno{
        StatuCode = 200,
        MensagemRetorno = "data atual menor que 16"
    };
}


public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Emitir(NotaViewModel nota)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    var prestador = await DbContext.GetContribuinteByUserIdAsync(this.User.Identity.GetUserId());

    Retorno retorno = await VerificarDam(nota, prestador);

    var valueNota = new Nota
    {
        Valor1 = nota.Valor1,
        Valor2 = nota.Valor2,
        Valor3 = nota.Valor3,
        Valor = nota.CofiValorns,
    };
    DbContext.Servicos.Add(valueNota);

    await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    nota = await GetNotaAsync(valueNota);

    if (retorno.StatuCode == 200)
        return Ok(retorno);
    else
        return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, retorno));     
}
```

Comment: Não falta um return no método VerificarDam?

Comment: eu adicionei o `return` onde tinha o `var msg = "Mensagem de teste atraso.....";` e o `BadRequest("Existem pendências. Entre em contato com ...");`  tem mais algum lugar que você deseja retornar algo?

Comment: Digo no final do bloco desse if (dataAtual.Day >= 16), não deveria retornar o objeto Retorno?

Comment: verdade, não me atentei a todos `If's`